# How to access entity records if not in menu/sitemap?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

Is there any way how to access records of an entity which is not visible in menu/sitemap? Or the only way how can I look at these records is to allow the entity to be visible in the sitemap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Advanced Find.

You can query the records and also create a new record from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create URLs to navigate to anything you want, see [Open forms, views, dialogs and reports with a URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg328483.aspx).

> **To open the Closed Opportunities view for Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online:**
>
> ```
> http://myorg.crm.dynamics.com/main.aspx?etn=opportunity&pagetype=entitylist&viewid=%7b00000000-0000-0000-00AA-000010003006%7d&viewtype=1039
> ```